# Why is viewWillTransition(to size:...) not working if I navigate away from and back to the View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have a `UIView` subclass called `myView` that is supposed reconfigure itself when  the device orientation changes. I'm using the `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` method in the `UIViewController` to call the `setUp()` method that reconfigures the view. The problem I am having is that it works the first time I load that particular view controller, but if I navigate away then back to it the code no longer works. What's wrong? The code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.myView.setUp()
}
```

If I use the deprecated method `didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)` instead, the code works properly every time.

Comment: Check if viewWillTransition function call or not when you revisit view

Comment: It is calling. Also, self.myView.setUp() is being called each time. I suspect that the issue has to do with a bad reference or something, as if the myView that is visible is no longer the one that is actually being called. What I have above is a very simplified version of the code, but I don't know what else to include, and there is too much to put all of it in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I still haven't figured out why the original problem is happening, but I did figure out a workaround. Ordinarily it would be possible to just calculate the orientation based on `UIScreen.main.bounds` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method, but I have a timer that is firing at the screen refresh rate, so that method is being called 60 times/second, and my `myView.setUp()` method is way too processor intensive for that to be workable. So, I've given my `UIViewController` an `orientation` property with a setter observer, with that property being calculated and set within `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. The setter observer then calls the `setUp()` method if the orientation changes. I'm still curious why the other method isn't working, but the workaround will do.

Answer (score 0):

Since `self.myView.setUp()` is being called each time I suspect the view is not updating due to a bad reference.

Try making it strong, if it is a case of a bad reference then this should fix it

```
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
```